# Proving P is a prime ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

I am studying ring theory and trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$ not containing $0$. Let $P$ be a maximal element in the set of ideals of $R$ whose intersection with $S$ is empty.  Prove that $P$ is a prime ideal.

I want to check this: is $S=R-P$ from the construction?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take $S=\{1,2,2^2,2^3,\dots\}$ and $P=(3)$.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks. Then now I see my proof fails since I assumed $S=R-P$. Do you have any idea how to prove the statement?

Comment: Supposing we have some $a,b\not\in P$ with $ab\in P$, we find that $(a)+P,(b)+P$ are larger than $P$ so contain some elements $s,t$ of $S$. Try to show $st$ is in $P$.

Answer (score -1):

There is a general bijection
$$
\{\text{ideals of $R$ disjoint with $S$}\}\leftrightarrow
\{\text{ideals of $S^{-1}R$}\}
$$
that preserves the inclusions and primality of ideals.

By maximality of $P$ among ideals disjoint from $S$ the ideal $S^{-1}P$ is maximal in $S^{-1}R$ hence prime. But then $P$ was prime by the correspondence.